# How to generate secure one time download link in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, security

I have a mobile application for selling tutorial videos.
I need to generate a unique one-time download link to display them in my application.

The application is API based and I'm using Laravel framework for Back-end. I saved all device id sent from android.

How can I generate a link for each users purchased products for any device?

Comment: you can refer `url` section of documentation. use https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate unique token for every app that user purchases.

```
$token = sha1(uniqid(time(), true));
```

When there is request for download, you can just destroy

```
$url = "http://example.com/activate.php?token=$token";
```

You can check the token for the respective user and do what you want.

Thanks

Comment: how to refer this link to my video file for display in mobile application?

Comment: If you are using laravel backend than you must be using api. That is just one example, now you have to create route for that some thing like:   `Route::get('user/{id}/app/{token}', 'UserControllerController@methodname');`

Answer (score 13):

You can use "Signed URLs" (Laravel >= 5.6 ). These URLs have a "signature" hash appendede. Next method creates a signed url

```
URL::signedRoute('video.download', ['user_id' => 1, 'video_id'=1]);
```

If you would like to generate a temporary signed route URL that expires, you may use the  temporarySignedRoute method:

```
URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'unsubscribe', now()->addMinutes(30), ['user' => 1]
);
```

Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#signed-urls

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP has asked for one-time use urls. Putting an expiry date does not make it one time use

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have to set this up yourself, I've made a small package to help with creating signed URLs with limited lifetimes and clicks.

https://github.com/linkeys-app/signed-url/

This will give you more functionality than the built in signed URLs laravel offers since you can set the number of clicks on a link before expiration. In this case, you'd just need to use:

```
Link::generate('myurl.com/download', ['user' => 1, 'video' => 5], null, 1);
```

This will allow you to attach data to a link, give it no expiry date (although passing an expiry date into the third parameter will expire the link at a given time) and only allow a single click before the link expires.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `unique key` for each user and send the key with the request when download.

When a user request for the product, check the key is already exists or not and also check if the key `belongs to` the user.

Comment: If device is also your concern, then you can store the device id also and check unique key belongs to both device and user or not.